# Install Spyder OS Mojave

Tags: anaconda, spyder, macos-mojave

I have a mac book pro mid 2015 which was running OS Monetary perfectly fine with Anaconda distribution and Spyder IDE installed, until yesterday when my OS crashed and I has to format the SSD.

I opted factory reset which installed OS El Capitan which I upgraded to OS Mojave 10.14.6

Since then, I am trying to install Spyder IDE, through conda distribution, through standalone .dmg setup file etc etc.

Every time, after installation, the Spyder IDE does not launch, but give Launch error message. See py2app website for debugging.

I have no idea about it.

Can you please help.?

I am trying to install Spyder IDE, through conda distribution, through standalone .dmg setup file etc etc.

Every time, after installation, the Spyder IDE does not launch, but give Launch error message. See py2app website for debugging.

I have no idea about it.